# Autohotkey Windows 10 Virtual Desktops

Tags: windows, windows-10, autohotkey, virtual-desktop, windows-virtual-desktop

I have an AHK script which saves window positions.
At the moment I save Title, X, Y, Width, Height, Class, FullPath etc.
I also want to save on which Virtual Desktop they are located on.

I dont know how Windows 10 handles Virtual Desktops:
Do they have a UID?
Do these UIDs change after a reboot?
Is there any way to actually number them?

I would like to do it in a way which has a low chance of breaking in case of a Windows update, but obviously that's mostly a dream.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [How can autohotkey detect which virtual desktop you're on?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55855959/3419297).

Comment: can you create a script within your virtual desktop? or use share clipboard feature..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can autohotkey detect which virtual desktop you're on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47778700/how-can-autohotkey-detect-which-virtual-desktop-youre-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an ahk function library,

to get the desktop (number) a window is on, use `VD_getDesktopOfWindow(wintitle)`, where `wintitle` can be combination of
`WinTitle`, `ahk_class`, `ahk_exe`, `ahk_id`, etc.

https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/VD.ahk

I've just made a script "list VD of all windows.ahk" in folder "other examples" to do what you need

It gets every window in every VD, and tells you, in order of VD, which windows are inside it.

```
Desktop 1: program.exe
Desktop 1: otherProgram.exe
Desktop 2: foobar.exe
Desktop 3: youGetThePoint.exe
```

the actual format is different

https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/VD.ahk/blob/master/other%20examples/list%20VD%20of%20all%20windows.ahk

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, thank you
I'll start working on my script again, I'll add your credits for this script of course and comply with AHK licensing guidelines

Comment: What does “the actual format is different” mean? What is the link that follows that statement?